# Comparing instances to get differences and attribute names

Tags: ruby

I have a class animal

```
class Animal
    def initialize( a, b, c)
        @aa=a
        @bb=b
        @cc=c
    end
end
```

I'm trying to compare these instances:

```
animal_original = Animal.new(1,2,3)
animal_to_compare = Animal.new(11,2,3)
```

I need a method to compare these two instances and get the differences in terms of the name of the variable and the values.

In this case, I will need an array containing `aa` (it's the name of the variable), the value of the first object, and the value of the second to be like this:

```
["aa", "1", "11"] #returned value
```

I tried to do it getting all the instance variables of the object, and converting them to a map to make the compare more easily with this function:

```
  def inst_vars obj
     obj.instance_variables.map do |att|
       { att => obj.instance_variable_get(att) }
     end
  end
```

But I cannot accomplish this. How can I do it to make the comparison and get all the values that I need?

Comment: Don't be afraid to up vote answers you find useful.  It helps the community find good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this method:

```
def compare_animals(obj1, obj2)
  out = []
  obj1.instance_variables.map do |var|                                                                                            
    if obj1.instance_variable_get(var) != obj2.instance_variable_get(var)  
      out << var.to_s.slice(/[^@]./)
      out << obj1.instance_variable_get(var)
      out << obj2.instance_variable_get(var)
    end
  end
  out
end
```

You can call it with this:

```
compare_animals animal_original, animal_to_compare
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
class Animal
  def initialize(a, b, c)
    @aa=a
    @bb=b
    @cc=c
  end

  def inst_vars obj
     obj.instance_variables.map do |att|
       [ att, instance_variable_get(att), obj.instance_variable_get(att) ]
     end.select do |att, one, two|
       one != two
     end
  end
end
```

I've attempted to re-use as much of the given logic as I could.

note: This does return an array of arrays. eg:

```
2.4.1 :046 > animal_original = Animal.new(1,2,3)
 => #<Animal:0x007ffdf718da10 @aa=1, @bb=2, @cc=3>
2.4.1 :047 > animal_to_compare = Animal.new(11,2,3)
 => #<Animal:0x007ffdf7119980 @aa=11, @bb=2, @cc=3>
2.4.1 :048 > animal_original.inst_vars animal_to_compare
 => [[:@aa, 1, 11]]
```

Or with multiple differences:

```
2.4.1 :049 > animal1 = Animal.new(1,2,3)
 => #<Animal:0x007ffdf717ed80 @aa=1, @bb=2, @cc=3>
2.4.1 :050 > animal2 = Animal.new(1,3,4)
 => #<Animal:0x007ffdf715c7d0 @aa=1, @bb=3, @cc=4>
2.4.1 :051 > animal1.inst_vars animal2
 => [[:@bb, 2, 3], [:@cc, 3, 4]]
```